# Error "ORA-01830": date format picture ends before converting entire input string (Oracle Error)

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

Please help, this my query:

```
SELECT   a.verifierid, a.peerverifier, periode AS last_periode,
         endToEndDelayMedian / 1000 AS x_medianroundtriplatency,
         medianJitter / 1000 AS x_maxjitter, percentLostPackets,
         CASE
WHEN (endToEndDelayMedian / 1000) < 80
AND (endToEndDelayMedian / 1000) > 0 THEN
    1
WHEN 80 <= (endToEndDelayMedian / 1000)
AND (endToEndDelayMedian / 1000) < 100 THEN
    2
ELSE
    3 end as sign_latency,
         CASE
            WHEN (medianJitter / 1000) < 5
            AND (medianJitter / 1000) > 0
               THEN 1
            WHEN 5 <= (medianJitter / 1000)
            AND (medianJitter / 1000) < 30
               THEN 2
            ELSE 3
         END AS sign_jitter,
         CASE
            WHEN percentLostPackets < 0.5
               THEN 1
            WHEN 0.5 <= (percentLostPackets)
            AND (percentLostPackets) < 1
               THEN 2
            ELSE 3
         END AS sign_packetlost,
         last_update
    FROM (select to_char(case when periode like '201%' then to_date(periode,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
else to_date(periode,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') periodex, a.*
from nextone_brix_l3vpn a ) a
         INNER JOIN
         (SELECT   verifierid, peerverifier, MAX (periode) AS last_periode
              FROM nextone_brix_l3vpn
          GROUP BY verifierid, peerverifier) b
         ON a.verifierid = b.verifierid
       AND a.peerverifier = b.peerverifier
       AND periode = b.last_periode
where 1=1  and to_char(periodex,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') between SYSDATE - INTERVAL '24' HOUR AND SYSDATE and rownum<=10
ORDER BY sign_packetlost DESC,
         sign_latency DESC,
         sign_jitter DESC,
         verifierid ASC
```

> Error "ORA-01830": date format picture ends before converting entire
>   input string (Oracle Error)

Comment: I have updated your [text formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). But, please always care about the [text formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your other posts.

Comment: Without seeing some of your data this is going to be difficult. At least one of the string date values in your data does not match the date format you are applying the TO_DATE on.

Comment: Yes @Ollie think that is my problem, but i don't know how to solve it. I have 65661056 recodrs on the table from my client.
This is a sampe data from column PERIODE = **2015-08-20 00:00:04**

Comment: @r5d thanks for remind me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that the data in PERIODE could be either `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` or `MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

Somewhere in your data this expected format is not holding true.

You can test this with:

```
SELECT to_char(
           case 
              when periode like '201%' then to_date(periode,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
              else to_date(periode,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
            end,
        'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') periodex
  FROM nextone_brix_l3vpn;
```

Running this should cause the ORA-01830 error you are seeing in your original code.

To identify where your erroneous record(s) are, try this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
   v_converted_date DATE;
BEGIN
   -- Enable the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

   -- Start your output
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Starting loop');

   -- Loop through your data table
   FOR i IN (SELECT rowid, periode FROM nextone_brix_l3vpn)
   LOOP
      -- Start a new Pl/SQL block
      BEGIN
        -- Try your data conversion
        v_converted_date := CASE
                               WHEN i.periode LIKE '201%' 
                               THEN TO_DATE(i.periode,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
                               ELSE TO_DATE(i.periode,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
                             END;
      EXCEPTION
         -- Trap the exception and output the rowed of the problem record
         WHEN others
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: '||sqlcode||', caused by record at row: '||i.rowid||' with PERIODE value: '||i.periode);
      END;
   END LOOP;

   -- End your output
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Loop finished');
EXCEPTION
   -- Trap any other exceptions and report them
   WHEN others
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

This should then output a list of the records that are causing you formatting issues.

```
Caveats:
```

1. I do not have a SQL session to test this code so you might need to hack it a bit to get it working
2. There are other ways to output the records other than using DBMS_OUTPUT so feel free to do it however is easiest for you
3. Yes, this means that you'll have to run through ever one of your 65m records and someone might be able to suggest a faster pure SQL method for identifying the problem records
4. You shouldn't really be storing dates in the database as VARCHAR's for precisely this reason, if it's a date, store it in a `DATE` datatype!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Ollie & http://stackoverflow.com/ you're so helpful. How to give you a witness of thanks in http://stackoverflow.com/ ?
i'm newbie here.

Comment: @FaisalTahir, you have already done enough by marking the answer as correct. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

your  problem is here in the date

```
 to_date(periode,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    else to_date(periode,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') periodex, a.*
    from nextone_brix_l3vpn a ) a
```

what is the value of period ? it should be like this `'15/09/2015 00:00:00'`

example: `select To_date ('15/09/2015 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  From DUAL;`